# How to use inline comments to document members in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, documentation-generation, xml-documentation

How can I document a member inline in .Net? Let me explain. Most tools that extract documentation from comments support some kind of inline documentation where you can add a brief after the member declaration. Something like:

```
public static string MyField; /// <summary>Information about MyField.</summary>
```

Is there a way to do this in C# or the .NET languages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. XML comments are only supported as a block level comment, meaning it must be placed before the code element you are documenting. The common tools for extracting XML comments from .NET code do not understand how to parse inline comments like that. If you need this ability you will need to write your own parser.

Comment: Doxygen supports this, so you don't need to write your own parser.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a built-in way to do this. The XML documentation system is hierarchical; it defines a relationship between the tag `<summary />` and the data that immediately follows it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just put it BEFORE the thing you want to comment

```
/// <summary>Information about MyField.</summary>
public static string MyField;
```

Comment: I know I can put it before. I'm asking if I can put it after in the same line.

Comment: That's not an inline comment.

Comment: // specifies an inline comment as opposed to /* for multiline

This is what I thought you meant.  No, there is no way of putting it AFTER.  How would the compiler know you didn't want to apply it to the following line?

Comment: Most parsers use a character to understand that the documentation is referring to the symbol prior to the comment. Something like:

public static string MyField; //- <summary>Information</summary>

When the parser sees //- as opposed to /// it knows it is documentation for the preciding symbol.

Comment: It's perfectly simple: A comment appearing after code *on the same line* refers to the preceding code. But no, this isn't supported with XML comments.